# Recovering Original Win8 to Toshiba Satellite c850 after formatting hard disk

Tags: hard-drive-recovery

I have Toshiba Satellite c850 B516 with Original Win8 installed.
I accidentally formatted the internal hard disk.
There is no serial number written on the bottom of my laptop.
How can I recover my original Win8 even if all my personal data is lost.

Comment: The license key is embedded the installed will automatically detect the key

Comment: Sorry I could not get you. "the installed will automatically detect the key"! What installation are you referring to?

Comment: The Windows installer will automatically detect your Windows 8 license.  **You basically asked how to install it.**

Comment: Thank you for your assistance. May be I didn't clarify my problem. My Toshiba Satellite c850 was accidentally formatted. I can install a non genuine Win8 but I will lose my license & other upgrading issues. I want to get my laptop to its original status when first purchased.

Comment: Have you tried running any form of bootable disk recovery? Even if it can't recover the OS (it likely won't) it may be able to recover the .swm files in your recovery partition.

Answer (score -1):

Did you get a Win8 disk? You probably should have got a serial no. Maybe it's in the packaging? You can install windows 8 anyway without the key and then enter it in after so ring up toshiba would be my next step.

Comment: No There was no Win8 disk when I purchased my laptop.As for installing Win8 without having the serial number I prefer not. I wonder if there's a way to recover Win8 from the Bios!!

Comment: @A.Ibnuhazm - Windows cannot be installed without an installation disk.  You cannot install Windows from the BIOS, BIOS, does not contain the Windows installer. **There is hardware that has the license key embedded this hardware is on ALL Windows 8 hardware.**

Comment: Many thanks to you, Now I understand that I need to purchase Win8 disk in order to install windows. If this is the case then I understand that I lost my prev. license back. am I correct? Your pacience is very much appreciated. The point is that, do I need to purchase a new license or not?

Comment: By the way, there was no recovery disk or any other disks with my laptop when first purchased.

Comment: You can download a windows 8 iso online. Try thepiratebay or possibly even on microsofts site. Then google how to put it on a usb and you can install from the usb. (or you can burn a disc if you have a dvd burner). If as Ramhound said is true then you will not need a key you just install this iso and it will be a genuine copy because the key is in your hardware.